# is there a one cell formula for getting a comma separated list with increasing numbers in EXCEL

Tags: excel, join, excel-formula, office365, repeater

Look at the picture below: I have 3 cells containing the starting number(B4=1), the increment number (C4=2) and the desired amount of numbers in the list (D4=3). In F4 I would like to have a list of comma separated values in F4 (1,3,5).
I tried something with REPT : B4&REPT(","&1(something like+C4);D4-1), but I do not know how to increase each repetion value.

[image: ;]

Comment: `TEXTJOIN` and `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: It depends on what version of Excel you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,SEQUENCE(C1,,A1,B1))
```

with the starting value in **A1**, the increment in **B1** and the number of items in **C1**.

[image]